# "elsarticle" toc and babel conflict?

Tags: table-of-contents, babel, elsarticle

How to correct the missplaced Appendix in the `toc` of `elsarticle`-documentclass? The title of the appendices is printed over the description *Appendix* in

[image]

```
\documentclass[preprint]{elsarticle}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\section{Document Preamble}

Proofs and so

\appendix

\section{a } Too irrelevant for the main document ...

\section{b } but used there as well.

\end{document}
```

A second problem is that if one aditionally loads`\usepackage[english]{babel}` the appendix labels *A* and *B* are displayed wrong as well:

[image]

Comment: This seems to be two bugs in `elsarticle`

Comment: @c.p You could try with the latest elsarticle.cls (elsarticle 2009/09/17, 1.20b).  I have got the correct output.

Comment: @SunilkumarKS I downloaded it last week. I presume it's the last version.

Comment: If you could not get the latest version from CTAN, you will get it from http://download.river-valley.com/elsarticle/elsarticle.cls, this is maintained by River Valley Technologies (India).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Two bugs in `elsarticle`.

The first one is that it doesn't take into account that `\numberline{Appendix A}` will make an overfull box, as it doesn't fit in the allotted 1.5em space.

The second one is related to `babel`. The class does `\def\appendixname{Appendix }`, but when `babel` is loaded, `\appendixname` will not have a trailing space.

### Fixes

Tested with and without `babel`.

```
\documentclass{elsarticle}
%\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{etoolbox,calc}

\makeatletter
\def\appendixname{Appendix}% don't add the space here
\appto\appendix{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\patch@l@section}% patch \l@section
  \appto\appendixname{ }% here add a trailing space
}
\protected\def\patch@l@section{%
  \patchcmd{\l@section}{1.5em}{\widthof{\appendixname\space}+2.5em}{}{}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\section{Document Preamble}

Proofs and so

\appendix

\section{a} Too irrelevant for the main document ...

\section{b} but used there as well.

\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]